# Java - Using Generics or Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, architecture

I have an interface, `Resource`, which is supposed to wrap *something* and expose a few operations on the wrapped object.
My first approach was to write the following, with the **Strategy** pattern in mind.

```
interface Resource<T> {
    ResourceState read();
    void write(ResourceState);
}

abstract class AbstractResource<T> implements Resource<T> {
    // This is where the Strategy comes in.
    protected AbstractResource(ResourceStrategy<T> strat) {
        // ...
    }

    // Both the read and write implementations delegate to the strategy.
}

class ExclusiveResource<T> extends AbstractResource<T> { ... }
class ShareableResource<T> extends AbstractResource<T> { ... }
```

The two implementations above differ in the locking scheme used (regular locks, or read-write locks).

There is also a `ResourceManager`, an entity responsible for managing these things.
My idea of usage by the client, would be:

```
ResourceManager rm = ...
MyCustomObject o = ...
MyCustomReadWriteStrategy strat = ...
rm.newResourceFor(o, "id", strat);
```

This way, the client would know about resources, but wouldn't have to deal directly with resources (hence the package-private classes). Also, I could make my own implementation of some common resources, like sockets, and the client would only ask for them (*ie*, I would have to write a `SocketStrategy implements ResourceStrategy<Socket>`).

```
ResourceManager rm = ...
rm.newSocketResource("id", host, port);
```

To access resources, he would request an handler from the manager. This is due to each thread having some specific access privileges, and so the manager would create an handler with the appropriate access privileges.

```
// This is in the ResourceManager class.
public ResourceHandler getHandlerFor(String id) {
    if (!canThreadUseThisResource(id)) throw ...;
    if (isThreadReaderOnly()) {
         return new ResourceReadHandler( ... );
    } else {
         return new ResourceWriteHandler( ... );
    }
}
```

This is where the problem kicks in.
This approach seems *clean and clear* to me, it also seems to be intuitive for the user.
But, as hinted, the manager keeps a mapping from identifiers to resources. How would this be declared, and how would the manager retrieve the resources from the map?

```
Map<String, Resource<?>> map;
// Can I go around without any specific cast? Not sure yet.
Resource<?> r = map.get(id);
// This could have an enum ResourceType, to check if thread has privileges
// for the specific type.
```

**Is this design acceptable, and/or following good practices?**

---

Alternatively, I could wipe out the generics, and have `ExclusiveResource` and `ShareableResource` be abstract and public.
These classes would then be extended, both by me and the client, for every type of resource needed (`FileResource extends ExclusiveResource`, `SocketResource extends ExclusiveResource`, ...).
This would probably eliminate the need for the strategy pattern, but would expose more of my package to the user.

**Which of these alternatives is the most correct, or widely accepted as good practice?**

---

**Edit:** After some thought, I think I could be able to remove the generic from the `Resource` interface, since that's the one causing trouble, and leave it on `AbstractResource` and its subclasses. The latter could still grant me compile-time verification of the strategies used.

```
public <T> void newExclusiveResourceFor(
        T obj, String id, ResourceStrategy<T> strat) {
    ExclusiveResource<T> r = new ExclusiveResource<>(obj, strat);
    map.put(id, r);
}
```

However, following the inheritance way seems to be more correct.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote? Let me know if the question could use improvement.

Comment: Resource<?> takes away the benefit of generics. It can hold anything and everything. In my view you can wipe out generics here.

Comment: @dkaustubh I see your point, and I agree. The generics here would be just a way to ensure that user-defined resoures receive an appropriate Strategy, since the Resources aren't directly accessible to the user. But I guess following the inheritance way I can achieve the same goals and yet be using appropriate tools.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the `Resource<T>` generic declaration because none of its members use `T` - is there a good reason for that interface to be generic?

Comment: @PaulBellora As a matter of fact, I think there isn't, as I pointed out a while ago in the update to the question. It would probably be best just to take the generic out of the interface, even if it stays in the implementations.

Comment: @afsantos Gotcha, sorry for not reading carefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [dkaustubh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1896893/dkaustubh) and [Paul Bellora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697449/paul-bellora), as it stands, there is no plausible justification for the generic in the `Resource` interface. This had gone completely unnoticed by me, at first, since I wanted the implementations to be generic, so I assumed the interface should also be generic. That's not the case.

I still have two options here.

### Using Generics

I should remove the generic in the interface. Then, I would end up with the following.

```
interface Resource {
    ResourceState read();
    void write(ResourceState);
    void dispose();
}

abstract class AbstractResource<T> implements Resource {
    /* This is where the Strategy comes in.
     * The generic ensures compile-time verification of the
     * strategy's type. */
    protected AbstractResource(ResourceStrategy<T> strat) {
        // ...
    }

    // Both the read and write implementations delegate to the strategy.
}

class ExclusiveResource<T> extends AbstractResource<T> { ... }
class ShareableResource<T> extends AbstractResource<T> { ... }

// This is the behaviour the client implements, for custom resources.
public abstract class ResourceStrategy<T> {
    public abstract ResourceState read(T obj);
    public abstract void write(ResourceState state);
    public abstract void dispose(T obj);
}
```

Only `ResourceHandler`, `ResourceManager`, `ResourceState` and `ResourceStrategy` need to be public, to the client.

---

### Using Inheritance

Using inheritance, I can achieve the same results, with some trade-offs.

```
public interface Resource {
    ResourceState read();
    void write(ResourceState);
    void dispose();
}

/* These implement only the locking schemes. */
abstract class ExclusiveResource implements Resource { ... }
abstract class ShareableResource implements Resource { ... }

/* The user extends these for custom content and behaviour. */
public abstract class CustomExclusiveResource
        extends ExclusiveResource { ... }
public abstract class CustomShareableResource
        extends ShareableResource { ... }
```

Resources are now public to the client.

---

### Conclusions

1. There are ways to misuse resources with both approaches, bypassing the expected contracts and thread permissions. Both approaches are equal here.
2. With generics, the inner representation of resources need not be known by the client, since the manager creates the resources *in the background*. With inheritance, resource creation takes place on the client side, so the manager's API would change to accept provided resources.
3. Even though `Resource`s are not public, using generics, the client needs to know about the strategies. With inheritance, these are gone, and the `public` status is assigned to resources instead.
4. With strategies, the behaviour can be changed in runtime, or there could be different behaviours for the same kind of resource. Without them, the client needs to dispose of a resource, and them re-create it using another subclass that implements different behaviour.
   E.g.: small files can be completely read to memory, while large files may require an appropriately sized buffer.

Unless something else is missing, it may just be a matter of choice, and thinking about the desired API and use cases.